# connection php and postgreSQL

Tags: php, database, postgresql, authentication

I'm have a problem. I want connect PHP and PostgreSQL, but don't know how.

HTML:

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Título -->
    <title>test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font-Awesome CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Ubicua-cloud CSS -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "" name = "f1" method = "post" style = "">
      <input type = "text" id = "telefone">
      <button type = "button" id = "init">iniciar sessão</button>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Ubicua-cloud-js -->
    <script src="login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

DB connect:

```
<?php 
 $connect=pg_connect ("host=localhost dbname=test port=5432 user=postgres password=28974220")or
 die("Error");
?>
```

JS to catch user informations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#init').click(function(){
        var telefone=$('#telefone').val();
        alert(telefone);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            url:'login.Ajax.php',
            data:{telefone:telefone},
            success: function(response){
                if(response.resposta==true){
                    $('#msg').html(response.msg);
                    window.location='test.php';
                }
                else{
                    $('#msg').html(response.msg);
                }
            },error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The PHP code to validate informations:

```
<?php
    include_once('includes/connect.php');
    $msg_ok=false;
    $msg_error='O sistema está indisponível.';
    if(isset($_POST['telefone']))
        if($_POST['telefone']!="")
            $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
            $consulta=pg_query($connect, ("Select * from test where telefone='$telefone"));
            if(pg_num_rows($consulta)>0)
                $msg_ok=true;
                $usua=pg_fetch_array($consulta);
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id']=$usua[0];
                $_SESSION['telefone']=$usua[1];
                $msg_error='Logado';
            else
                $msg_error='Telefone não existe.';
            endif;
        else
            $msg_error='Telefone incorreto.';
        endif
    else
        $msg_error='Erro.';
    endif;
    $saidaJson=array('resposta' => $msg_ok, 'msg' => msg_error);
    echo json_encode($saidaJson);
?>
```

I received error messages to catch user informations, help, please.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using PDO. If so, you need make changes to the database connection file(substitute the variables with your database values):

```
<?php 
   $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host";port=$port, $dbuser, $dbpass); 

?>
```

Comment: I solved the problem, but now have an other...You can help? I'll edit the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but now I'm needing exchange informations between the php and js...I have a script that simulates a person typing and need it to talk to users calling them by their proper names, but I don't know how, I need concatenate one variable in JS, but before that I need store one PHP variable in one JS variable.

```
var init = document.getElementById('init_text');
var init_text = 'Hi <nome>, I'm your friend!';

function digit(str, el) {
  var char = str.split('').reverse();
  var typer = setInterval(function () {
  if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
    var next = char.pop();
    el.innerHTML += next;
  }, 60);
}

digit(init_text, init);
```